# How to add a modifier to a collection(group? linked objects? IDK) which it has modifiers inside

Tags: mesh, modifiers, objects, mirror, groups

I'm a beginner to blender and I'm trying to make a cnc model using some different objects which have mirror modifier inside the group(e.g. the bars).

And now I want to add an array modifier to let it line up in a row.

Here is the problem: If I add this modifier, only the first object will be applied,like this pic I put:
[image]

I tried using `ctrl`+`j` to make them toghther and then add modifier,
but this will erase the mirror modifier I added just like the pic below:
[image]

The last thing I can do is to save it as another type of model file then imput, but I think there must be a better way. So any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, no, you cannot add modifiers to collections.
In you pic your are adding the modifier to 'Cube' as it is the selected object.

You can however copy modifiers to other objects with <kbd>CTRL+L</kbd>

For an array modifier, to keep all your parts relative to each other you'll need to use `Object Offset` and also have all the objects origins at the same point, this will break your mirror modifiers so they will need to use `Mirror Object` as their mirror point and select an object to use as the mirror point, or add an empty for this purpose.

The ***last*** object you select is the object to copy the modifiers from.

Also note, this is simply "copying", so any changes made to a modifier after this will NOT update the others.

In my example I have already set all the objects origins to the same point. I then use the Empty to control the spread of the array

[image]

Comment: Also make sure all objects use the same transform (same scale and rotation), because the array modifier offset depends on that

Comment: Thank you so much! I did it following your instruction. This gif animation is very easy to understand!